# Angular Flex cannot put items on the same line, Angular 8.2.1 and Flex-Layout 8.0.0.beta 26

Tags: html, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to align my boxes on one line, but allow wrapping and moving to column mode when the screen size is a small phone display.

I am trying to get:

`Wins     Losses        Ties     Points`

as the screen shrinks:

`Wins     Losses        Ties
Points`

HTML

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <div>Wins</div>
    <div>Losses</div>
    <div>Ties</div>
    <div>Points</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div *ngIf="(TeamStandings$ | async) as Data; else loading">
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayout.xs="column">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- While data is being returned via Observable, this is shown -->
    <ng-template #loading>
        Getting Data...
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

This still gives:

```
Wins
Losses
Ties
Points
1
2
3
```

This makes me wonder if the flex-layout module is working, but it is included in my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MaterialModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Each of the sls-number-box simply show a title in a formatted box.  However, these remain on individual lines regardless of the screen resolution.

```
Wins
Losses
Ties
Points
```

The blocks always show as if they are in a column, and never scroll up to be on the same row regardless of screen size.

The css for the number box has a set width and height of 100px.  This can be removed as well if there is a way to size the block inside the flex layout as well.  Note that if I remove the width and height from the CSS, then the boxes to size out to the available width, so it does appear that the flex-layout is working somewhat.

Comment: please share details of sls-number-box which might causing that issue

Comment: @NagaSaiA I removed my custom control based on the suggested answer, and even the simple text is not working correctly.  I think it must be the FlexLayoutModule not loading, but it is in my app.module.ts.

Comment: Scott,  i created stackblitz using above mentioned code snippet and it seems to be working fine- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkdjgv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks.  It was the main div being configured as display: inline-block; that fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Scott for confirming, I have posted same as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below css for the child div to inline-block elements

```css
.test div{
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="test">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkdjgv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

The way the flex layouts work (someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) is that, for example, your `fxLayout="row wrap"` will only work on direct child elements.

Right now, you have

```
<div> fxLayout="row wrap">
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Only that one div (two once you include your loading ng-template) will get put onto the row.

Something like this should otherwise work:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
  <div>Wins</div>
  <div>Losses</div>
  <div>Ties</div>
  <div>Points</div>
</div>
```

This would put each child div within the scope of the row flex layout, but this is not what you actually have. You need to remove that inner div (move the `*ngIf` to the outer div?) so that the components are direct children of the controlling flex. OR, add the same `fxLayout` directive to that child div so THAT div is a row layout...

Comment: Even using your simple example, I just get the 4 divs on top of themselves.  I have amended the question to be a very simple example then, removing my custom control for clarity.

Comment: The main CSS needs a div with display: inline-block; to fix this.